# Expression Engine + Solspace Rating Module - "Vote Up" a customer review

Tags: solspace-rating

Can you vote 'up' a review using Solspace Rating so that it'd do something like:

'5 out of 8 people found this review useful'

I've had a good look through the docs but don't see anything like this...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear so!

http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/rating_vote_stats/

This does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen other instances where people did not want to "vote up" the rating itself, but they wanted to "like" the product itself that you may be able to rate.

In order to get this functionality, people have used the Solspace Favorites plug-in.

Just thought I would add this info in case people run across this need too.